# Pass enum elements as event args C#

Tags: c#, events, enums, delegates

Is it possible to pass Enum elements as event arguments ?

Let's say I have..

```
public class Letters
{
    public delegate void StateChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event StateChangedEventHandler StateChanged;

    public AbcState state = AbcState.Aaa;     
    public AbcState State
    {
        get{return this.state;}
        set
        {
            this.state = value;
            this.OnStateChanged();
        }
    }

    public enum AbcState
    {
        Aaa,
        Bbb,
        Ccc
    }

    protected virtual void OnStateChanged()
    {
        StateChanged?.Invoke(this, State);
    }
```

See how I am trying to pass the element of the enum as an event argument?
Now, I normally would create a class and extends EventArgs, and then I would be able to pass the class itself.
And I know I could do the same here, Create a different class  extending EventArgs and then create the enum, field and property right in the class. And then make an instance of the latter into my class "Letters" (used in code above).

But, isnt that crazy ? There has to be a better way. Please tell me there is a simplier way.

By the way I do not know if the code above would compile I just wrote it straight in the Editor as I am not on my dev computer right now.

Comment: Complication of code is subjective. However, coding standards should be adhered to for purposes of standardizing how applications talk to each other. If your application will not be used by any other library, then stop reading here. The standard event delegate signature is there for a reason - i.e. `EventHandlerMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Again, subjective, but it is poor practice to deviate if there is any likelihood that the library will be referenced by another and events generated in your library to be consumed by another. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182133.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the parameter of the event to be the enum, then sure, just specify that as the signature when declaring the event:

```
public class Letters
{
    public event Action<AbcState> StateChanged;

    private AbcState state = AbcState.Aaa;     
    public AbcState State
    {
        get{return this.state;}
        set
        {
            this.state = value;
            this.OnStateChanged();
        }
    }

    public enum AbcState
    {
        Aaa,
        Bbb,
        Ccc
    }

    protected virtual void OnStateChanged()
    {
        StateChanged?.Invoke(State);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `EventHandler<AbcState>` instead. At least then event handlers use the `...(object sender, <T> e)` signature for event delegates. Better still, keeping the standard signature is better with an `AbcStateEventArgs` class: `EventHandler<AbcStateEventArgs>`. Code Analysis will puke all over event handlers that don't follow the standard implementation.

Comment: @IAbstract Adding all of that accomplishes nothing.  It complicates the code and provides no value.  Also, the OP specifically said that he knew how to do all of that, he asked how to avoid having to, and I obliged.

Comment: 'Complication' of code is subjective. Although, as a convention, there are assumptions made if libraries are used by other parties.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not that crazy. It's not at all crazy to follow conventions, even if they seem a little clunky sometimes, because then those who maintain your code (including you, after you forget writing this stuff) will find as few surprises as possible.

You do have the option of using `EventHandler<T>`, however:

```
public event EventHandler<AbcState> StateChanged;

protected void OnStateChanged(AbcState state)
{
    StateChanged?.Invoke(this, state);
}
```

By the way, you don't have to declare a new redundant delegate type to declare an event. This is the same as your original declaration:

```
public event EventHandler StateChanged;
```

The nicest thing might be to write something like this:

```
public class ValueEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public ValueEventArgs(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; protected set; }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
public event EventHandler<ValueEventArgs<AbcState>> StateChanged;

protected void OnStateChanged(AbcState state)
{
    StateChanged?.Invoke(this, new ValueEventArgs<AbcState>(state));
}
```

You could also write a `ValueChangedEventArgs<T>` with old and new value properties, etc. etc. But `EventHandler<AbcState>` is your quickest typesafe way to do what you want to.

Finally, you *can* use `Action<T>` as an `event` delegate, but that's a bad idea. People see `Action<T>` and they don't expect it to be an `event`. The only thing you're adding is confusion when somebody tries to read your code. Unless there is some specific, clear advantage to be had (and there's none here), don't write code which, at first glance, looks like something it isn't.

Comment: Using `Action` as the delegate for the event in no way inhibits multiple subscribers.  It *is* an event, even if you use `Action` as the delegate.

Comment: @Servy Nevertheless, it's a bad idea to write code that isn't what it looks like. Nobody expects an `Action` to be an event. Anything where you have to stop and say "WTF?" is a bad idea for maintainability.

Comment: That just demonstrates a lack of understanding of what events are in C#.  Yes, it might be confusing to cargo cult programmers that copy-paste code without understand what it's doing.  I suppose I have the luxury of generally not having such programmers as the target audience for maintainers of my code, but yes, there are some people not in such a position.

Comment: @Servy I'm paid to implement features. Just because you know how to do something in a deliberately opaque way doesn't mean you have to waste other people's time doing it. We're already stuck with more than enough "clever" code left behind by long-forgotten self-appointed geniuses. We've cleaned up the absolute garbage, but what's left is no prize.

Comment: It's not deliberately opaque.  It's simply implementing exactly the features needed, rather than doing a bunch of entirely unnecessary and unhelpful work just because you don't realize that it's accomplishing nothing.  That you think just not adding things you don't need is "clever" is fairly telling.  I simply don't consider "not adding pointless changes that nobody will ever use" clever, or "genius" level programming.  It *simplifies* the code by only providing what's relevant and not cluttering it with code unrelated to the semantics of the project.

Comment: @Servy Anything that requires additional effort from somebody reading your code isn't "simplifying" anything in any useful real-world sense. You're "optimizing" petty nonsense that doesn't need to be optimized. How many additional hours does it take you to type `EventHandler<AbcState>` rather than `Action<AbcState>`, on average? Rough order of magnitude here. Round numbers. Take all the time you need. The more the better.

Comment: I'll go with three to four orders of magnitude more time than it takes to wonder why an event only supplies the information that it needs, rather than the information it needs unnecessarily wrapped in a class that accomplishes nothing with an additional parameter that is never used and obscures its semantics by not properly leveraging the type system.

Comment: @Servy Are you still here?

Comment: Indeed I am still here.

Comment: @Servy Goodbye.

Comment: You guys win "Nerdiest nerds" award.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing prevents you from not following event handler convention:

```
public enum Test { X }

public class A
{
    public event Action<Test> StuffDone;    
}
```

And you'll be able to do this:

```
A a = new A();
a.StuffDone += test =>
{
    if(test == Test.X)
    {

    }
};
```

It's just a convention, not a language limitation.